# Am I allowed to use render :layout within render :layout in HAML 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm upgrading our app from rails 2.3.10 to 2.3.12, and in doing so had to upgrade from HAML 3.0.21 to 3.1.2.  It has broken in a few places, all of them where we used render :layout from within a template that was already inside a layout.  Is that an invalid use that HAML has now forbidden, or has it broken somewhere in HAML?

Comment: https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/403 suggests it's probably a bug in HAML

Comment: Can you provide the actual code snippet you're using to render the partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: http://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/403